Best way to present a case study that requires icon interaction and audio playback?
I'm creating a UX Sound & Audio Branding case study. There will be multiple short audio clips, which ideally should be activated by clicking speaker icons on the slides.

Which platform/method would be best to allow this feature or a similar alternative?

I'm designing the slides in Figma and previously i've hosted all my case studies on Behance. I'm not inclined to create my own website just yet.
One idea so far, which isn't fullproof :
Idea 1 : Hosting the case study as a Prototype in Figma. Linking it via Behance.

This would allow for audio playback and icon interaction quite easily.
The downsides being that Hiring managers will need to be familiar with Figma Prototype interactions to navigate through it. if they aren't, there could be issues when viewing it.
Another potential downside could be slide loading times. Not sure if it would be an issue though.

Can anyone chime in on an optimal method?

Netlify is one of the best for it, but there are many other like Github or Neocities
